# How to reset window.datalayer in nuxt3 app?

Tags: google-tag-manager, reset, nuxt3

```
export default (customPageTitle, addParams = {}) => {
 if (process.client) {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    window.dataLayer.push(() => {
        window.google_tag_manager[MYGTMID].dataLayer.reset()
    })

    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'page_view_meta',
        custom_page_title: customPageTitle,
        ...addParams
    });

    console.log(window.dataLayer);
 }
}
```

Hi, this is my Nuxt component for GMT-Tracking.
Problem: the window.dataLayer array size is increasing - I tried to reset the data layer with the method above, but this ist working. every route makes window.datalayer bigger and bigger.

Not sure what reset() fn should trigger. The function exists but seems nothing to do.

Any Ideas?

I am using nuxt3, universal mode.